# Un nom général pour désigner une structure juridique

Tags: noms, demande-de-mot, synonymes

Entreprise, association, organisation, boutique, entité commerciale ou administrative à but lucratif ou pas… etc.

Je cherche un nom court et générique qui peut remplacer toutes ces formes d'organisations.

J'hésite, car selon moi « organisation » est un nom général, mais il peut être aussi compris en tant qu'association internationale.

Comment: Here are a few more to add to your list to choose from: une collectivité/une société/un groupe/un groupement. I think that I prefer "une société," but not enough to make it an answer.

Comment: Personne morale ? Entité ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Organisation n'a pas forcément une connotation internationale, puisqu'on peut parler *d'organisation syndicale* ou *d’une organisation criminelle*. D'ailleurs, la définition exacte d'organisation est "
groupement qui se propose des buts déterminés"

Answer (score 5):

Si tu cherches un terme juridique, c'est *[personne morale](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personne_morale)*. Une personne morale est une entité qui peut posséder des biens, conclure des contrats, agir en justice, etc. Il peut s'agir d'une association à but non lucratif, d'une entreprise, d'émanations de l'état (collectivité territoriale, école, hôpital, …), etc.

Si tu cherches un mot de la vie courante, j'appuie la [proposition](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/12285) d'*organisation*. N'importe quelle personne morale peut être qualifiée d'organisation, c'est simplement une association de plusieurs personnes qui a une structure. Une organisation n'a pas forcément de personnalité juridique (par exemple, ce peut être une sous-structure au sein d'une association ou d'une entreprise), mais c'est le plus souvent le cas.

Answer (score 1):

On parlera aussi de [*véhicule*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/v%C3%A9hicule) (voir aussi [2](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A9hicule_%28homonymie%29))/véhicule juridique. Malheureusement il est fort difficile d'en trouver une définition satisfaisante:

> Montage financier ou structure juridique permettant la réalisation
>   d’un projet.

Le terme est utilisé de bien des manières: désignation de différentes formes et entités, structures et méthodes sous-jacentes, concepts juridiques particuliers etc. Relié possiblement au sens figuré, voir [instrument](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/v%C3%A9hicule), ou au sens premier: *Ce qui sert à transmettre, à transporter*.